Maximum value of $pq+pr+qr$ if $2p+3q+r=4$
Let $p,q,r \in \Bbb {R}$
Find the  maximum value of $pq+pr+qr$ if $2p+3q+r=4$.
I used Cauchy-Schwarz inequality and got $p^2+q^2+r^2≥8/7$. But after this, I am not able to proceed any further.
I feel AM-GM inequality should be used but I don't know on which terms should I use AM-GM inequality.

If we express $r$ in given condition we get quadratic function on $p$ (and $q$):
$$f(p) = -2p^2-4p(q-1)-(3q^2-4q)$$
which achieves the maximum value at $p=1-q$...

Wait, isn’t that @Ihatemaths edit some unnecessary things? “condition e” should be “condition we”.
